# Swift iOS. Program crashes when i try to mutate an array of buttons

Tags: arrays, swift, colors, crash, uibutton

I have about 20 buttons linked to `allKeys`. I want the turnRed button to change the color of their text to red. I tried the following code:

```
    @IBOutlet var allKeys: [UIButton]!


    @IBAction func turnRed(sender: UIButton) {
        var i = allKeys.count

        repeat {
            allKeys[i].setTitleColor(UIColor.redColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        i -= 1
        } while i != -1
    }
```

When I press the turnRed button, my program crashes and xcode jumps to the appDelegate file and highlights the AppDelegate class with the error Thread1: signal SIGABRT.

The console says "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException Reason: NSArrayI objectAtIndex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that you are setting the variable `i` to `allKeys.count`, but since arrays in swift start with zero, the twentieth element should actually be `allKeys[19]`. Thus, when the loop is at `i = 20`, it tries to access `allKeys[20]`, which crashes the app.

One way to solve this is to set `i` to `allKeys.count - 1` instead, but a better way would be to use a `for-in` loop instead of `repeat`.

```
for key in allKeys {
    key.setTitleColor(UIColor.redColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
}
```

There are multiple ways to loop in Swift, and you should use the options to your advantage. You can find Apple's documentation for **Control Flow** [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html).